# What's the meaning of "{# ... #}" tag in tpl file?

Tags: html, css, tags

What is the meaning of all {# ... #} tag on the code below?

```
 {include file="header.tpl" title="install" showheader="no"}

<div class="install" style="text-align:center;padding:5% 0 0 0;">
    <div style="text-align:left;width:500px;margin:0 auto;padding:25px 25px 15px 25px;background:white;border:1px solid;">

        <h1>{#installcollabtive#}</h1>

        <div style="padding:16px 0 16px 0;">
            <h2>{#installstep#} 3</h2>
            <em>{#createadmin#}</em><br /><br />

            <form class = "main" name = "adminuser" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "install.php?action=step3">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class = "row"><label for = "username">{#name#}:</label><input type = "text" name = "name" id = "username" /></div>
                    <div class = "row"><label for = "pass">{#password#}:</label><input type = "password" name = "pass" id = "pass" /></div>
                </fieldset>
                <br />
                    <div class="row-butn-bottom">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        <button type="submit"  onfocus="this.blur();">{#continue#}</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> {*Install end*}
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: are you using opencart?

Comment: no, i'm using collabtive (a project management software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables that are loaded from the config files are referenced by enclosing them within `#hash marks#`, or with the smarty variable `$smarty.config`. The later syntax is useful for embedding into quoted attribute values.

Example config file:

```
pageTitle = "This is mine"
bodyBgColor = '#eeeeee'
tableBorderSize = 3
tableBgColor = "#bbbbbb"
rowBgColor = "#cccccc"
```

A template demonstrating the `#hash#` method:

```
{config_load file='foo.conf'}
<html>
<title>{#pageTitle#}</title>
<body bgcolor="{#bodyBgColor#}">
<table border="{#tableBorderSize#}" bgcolor="{#tableBgColor#}">
<tr bgcolor="{#rowBgColor#}">
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Last</td>
    <td>Address</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

A template demonstrating the `$smarty.config` method:

```
{config_load file='foo.conf'}
<html>
<title>{$smarty.config.pageTitle}</title>
<body bgcolor="{$smarty.config.bodyBgColor}">
<table border="{$smarty.config.tableBorderSize}" bgcolor="{$smarty.config.tableBgColor}">
<tr bgcolor="{$smarty.config.rowBgColor}">
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Last</td>
    <td>Address</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it. In my case it reference to language config.